# Maximum call stack size exceeded cannot do nested populate

Tags: mongoose-populate

I have an issue about Mongoose nested populate

I try to get blog comment (comment is child of blog)

I have blog ,user schema

```
const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  parentId: { type: String },
  children: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }],
});
export default Blog;
```

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  image: String,
  blogs: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Blog" },
  onboarded: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

export default User;
```

and i made api call like **fetchBLogById**
and try to populate author and chidlren from blog like

```
 const singlePost = await Post.findById(id)
      .populate([
        { path: "author", model: User, select: "_id id name image" },
        { path: "children", model: Post },
      ])
      .exec();
```

But i cannot execute this action
How can i solve this problem?

I Would like to get children and user of children from blog